# mongodump stdout for a collection not working

Tags: mongodb

so im trying to dump a collection on mongodump through stdout so i can directly pipe it and gzip it.  But it's  giving me errors.

When i do:

```
mongodump --db test -u username -p Password -h mymongodatabase.onthecloud:12888 -vvvvv --collection posts --out -
```

it displays these errors:

```
Wed Feb 29 21:48:13 creating new connection to:mymongodatabase.onthecloud:12888
Wed Feb 29 21:48:13 BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
Wed Feb 29 21:48:13 connected connection!
connected to: mymongodatabase.onthecloud:12888
Wed Feb 29 21:48:13 nextSafe(): { $err: "unauthorized db:test lock type:-1 client:10.3.55.10", code: 10057 }
Wed Feb 29 21:48:13 User Assertion: 13106:nextSafe(): { $err: "unauthorized db:test lock type:-1 client:10.3.55.10", code: 10057 }
assertion: 13106 nextSafe(): { $err: "unauthorized db:test lock type:-1 client:10.3.55.10", code: 10057 }
```

but when i dunt include '--out -' it dumps the collection fine (doesn't give me aunauthorized error).  What's going on?

Comment: username and/or password error?

Comment: not it's not.  when i take out '--out -' im able to get the dump with the same credentials

Comment: this looks like a bug - I am able to use the stdout option just fine without authentication - just wondering if you could confirm that it works on a non-auth DB?  I am enabling auth now myself to test

Comment: ya i am able to stdout without authentication on a local mongodb.  Anyone else experiencing the same as me?

Comment: FYI this was bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5233 fixed in 2.1.2

Comment: ya i issued this bug... thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was a bug, issued and fixed:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5233